# SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've seen other questions with a similar error though their fixes did not solve my issue. Notice that I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Here is my models file:

```
class subjects(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(100))

class questions(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    accountID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    subjectID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    subject = db.relationship('subjects')
    topic = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
```

As you may see, I want `questions.subject` to refer to `subjects.subject`. I try to form a query:

```
topicList = db.session.query(questions.topic.distinct()).filter_by(subject=subjectID, accountID=accountID)
```

I receive an error stating `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

What does this error mean and how to I fix my code to prevent this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering by `subject`, but providing a string instead of an object. You either need to use an object

```
subject = db.session.query(subjects).get(subjectID)
topicList = db.session.query(questions.topic.distinct()).filter_by(subject=subject, accountID=accountID)
```

or you need to query by `subjectID`

```
topicList = db.session.query(questions.topic.distinct()).filter_by(subjectID=subjectID, accountID=accountID)
```

In either case, you appear to be using `subjectID` as a string when it should be an integer. I'm not sure how it's getting its initial value, but you'll want to address that there.